# What is the *Angular* way to get an elements siblings?

Tags: angularjs

What is the idiomatic way to get an elements siblings when it is clicked using AngularJS?

So far I've got this:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <div ng-click="clicked()">One</div>
    <div ng-click="clicked()">Two</div>
    <div ng-click="clicked()">Three</div>
</div>

<script>
    function FooCtrl($scope){
        $scope.clicked = function()
        {
            console.log("Clicked", this, arguments);
        };
    }
</script>
```

here's a jQuery implementation as a concrete example:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#foo div').on('click', function(){
            $(this).siblings('div').removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$event.currentTarget.previousElementSibling` and `$event.currentTarget.nextElementSibling` is used to the sibling details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an angular version of the jQuery sample that you provided:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <div ng-click="selected.item='One'" 
    ng-class="{clicked:selected.item=='One'}">One</div>
    <div ng-click="selected.item='Two'" 
    ng-class="{clicked:selected.item=='Two'}">Two</div>
    <div ng-click="selected.item='Three'" 
    ng-class="{clicked:selected.item=='Three'}">Three</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function FooCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {   
    $scope.selected = {
        item:""
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** You dont strictly need to access DOM for this. However if you still want to then you can write a simple directive. Something like below:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <div ng-click="clicked()" get-siblings>One</div>
    <div ng-click="clicked()" get-siblings>Two</div>
    <div ng-click="clicked()" get-siblings>Three</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
yourApp.directive('getSiblings', function() {
   return {
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope,element,attrs){
         scope.clicked = function () {
            element.siblings('div').removeClass('clicked');
            element.addClass('clicked');
         }
      }
   }
});
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/3RwST/)</kbd>

Comment: As written, I don't think that directive works.  I edited it to show a working version.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Yep jQuery is not required. jqLite is enough. Thanks for making my code functional.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I got rid of those `ng-click`s as well.

Comment: But what the answer now shows doesn't work again.  Also, as long as jQuery is included before Angular, you don't have to wrap your element  like so: `$(element)`.  We can simply use `element` directly.  Note, function `siblings()` is not provided by jqLite.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Oops! I did not notice that you actually did `scope.clicked`. I assumed it was `$(element).click`. Edited again :D

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to this one. Now I've got a bunch of Angular under my belt I can see this is the pattern I was looking for.

Answer (score 26):

Use a directive, since you want to traverse the DOM:

```
app.directive('sibs', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                element.parent().children().removeClass('clicked');
                element.addClass('clicked');
            })
        },
    }
});
```

```
<div sibs>One</div>
<div sibs>Two</div>
<div sibs>Three</div>
```

Note that jQuery is not required.

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/X2GLq/)</kbd>

Comment: @artdias90, if jQuery is not loaded on your page, Angular uses its own built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."  `removeClass()` and `addClass()` are part of jqLite, so you don't need jQuery for what I show above.  See [angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for more info.

Comment: In angular it's element.parentElement.children

Answer (score 1):

Following is a directive built exclusively with Angular grammar (borrowing from jqLite):

```
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, controllers) {
    var parentChildren,
        mySiblings = [];

    // add a marker to this element to distinguish it from its siblings
    // this could be a lot more robust
    iElement.attr('rsFindMySiblings', 'anchor');

    // get my parent's children, it will include me!
    parentChildren = iElement.parent().children();

    // remove myself
    scope.siblings = [];
    for (var i=0; i < parentChildren.length; i++) {
       var child = angular.element(parentChildren[i]);
       var attr = child.attr('rsFindMySiblings');
       if (!attr) {
         scope.siblings.push({name: child[0].textContent});  
       }
    }
}
```

Note that it uses a controller to store the results. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ziXA9uImgNlDef4z0Yri?p=info) for a detailed example